# New/Repeat Visitors in Adobe Analytics (omniture) vs Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, adobe-analytics

I was facing an issue of numbers not matching when i compared new/ repeat visitors in google analytics vs omniture.

Method of comparing :

1. Default report in google analytics
2. New/repeat plugin in Adobe Analytics
3. Segment created in adobe analtyics with visit number (>1, =1 )

is there a differnce in the ways adobe and google track repeated visitors ?

Comment: Both no and yes. They both use a cookie with a client id and use that to aggregate into sessions and visits, so the principle is the same. But they use different cookies, different tracking code and different reporting engines, so they will not arrive at the same result.

Comment: How large is the discrepancy, they may not exactly match, but they should not be out by that much. The things that can also impact this are related also to completeness of tagging on pages and how a visit is defined. For Adobe Analytics: "Visits: The number of sessions within a given time period. A visit is defined as a sequence of consecutive page views without a 30-minute interval, or continuous activity for 12 hours." not sure what google defines it as. Also the definition of the date range can make a difference.

Comment: In Adobe Analytics Reporting I think visits that start outside a date range are not included, even if some of the events are in the data range. Analytics Data Warehouse uses a different rule and would count those as a visit.

Comment: You might want to start by comparing pageviews - if those are roughly the same then it's just that they are aggregated differently in both tools. If you have a large discrepancy in pageviews (i.e. before data is aggregated) then this might point to a technical problem (or maybe you have just many users opt-out from one  tool but not the other).